# Jekyll via Bash on Windows 10: `jekyll new blog` returns error `Bundler: ruby: No such file or directory.`

Tags: windows-10, jekyll

I followed the instruction from the [jekyll for Windows](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/windows/) page, but cannot manage to get jekyll to work on my windows system.

After finishing the installation process (which requires separate handling of the nokogiri gem), trying to create a new jekyll page returns the error:

`root@LAPTOP-79P42G17:/mnt/c/Users/Stan# jekyll new asdf
Running bundle install in /mnt/c/Users/Stan/asdf...
  Bundler: ruby: No such file or directory -- /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/exe/bundle (LoadError)`

I've reinstalled all gems to no avail. `jekyll -v` returns `jekyll 3.7.2`, `ruby -v` returns `ruby 2.3.6p384 (2017-12-14 revision 61254) [x86_64-linux-gnu]`

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

Contrary to what the instruction say **install the most recent version of ruby**, otherwise conflicts will emerge, since all other components needed for jekyll are of the most recent version.

In my case [the most recent stable version of ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/) is 2.5, such that

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:brightbox/ruby-ng
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ruby2.5 ruby2.5-dev build-essential dh-autoreconf
```

was needed. The rest of the [installation steps](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/windows/) remain unchainged.